# update table row(child component) on click into current new state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in my react app I have a table on parent component and it's rows are render in a child component as follows

```
ViewINVCCartTableRow(){
 return this.state.cartProducts.map(function(object,i){
            return <ViewINVCTable obj={object} key={i} callbackSum = {this.callbackRowSum}  />;
        }.bind(this));
}
```

`cartProducts` is the object array that contain rows data. cartProducts is updated in componentdidmount from database. 
also i have a product add form. i want to update the table after submitting form.
following code is the form submit code

```
axios.post(backendde.backendUrl+'addINVC/addProductINVC',obj).then(res=>console.log(res.data));
...
axios.get(backendde.backendUrl+'addINVC/viewCart').then(response =>{
                this.setState({cartProducts:response.data});
            }).catch(function (error){console.log(error);});
```

currently after click submit button even though i have added setState function,cartProduct table row is mapped and rendered using the previous state.
when i click submit button for the second time, table is updated with first product and so on.
please help me with setstate function

Also I tried by inserting componentdidUpdate function with above axios.get function. actually it worked. but is uses CPU usage high (axios.get executes continuesly). so its not a good solution

Comment: Looks to me like you're trying to call `axios.get` before the `post` has necessarily resolved - leading to a race condition. You need to wait to call `get` until the `post` has happened - by putting it inside the `.then(...)` callback of `axios.post`. In fact you shouldn't really need to call `get` here, the `res.data` ought to have the data you need (if it doesn't, change your backend so that it does!).

Comment: great your comment is the solution
i put get function inside then in post function
thank you so much

Comment: I have put as an answer as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to you're trying to call `axios.get` before the post has necessarily resolved - leading to a race condition.

You need to wait to call get until the post has happened - by putting it inside the `.then(...)` callback of `axios.post`. In fact you shouldn't really need to call get here, the `res.data` ought to have the data you need (if it doesn't, change your backend if at all possible so that it does!)